# How to auto fill date after selecting current date and number of years

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have 2 text fields and 1 drop down box, if I have selected date in first text box after that I have to select number of year from drop down.

So how can I auto fill the next date in second text box of that selected no of year from drop down.

this is text box code

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tent"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="purchese_date" id="tbDate" class="pwaf form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['purchese_date']) ? $_POST['purchese_date'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Enter Purchese Date eg:dd/mm/yyyy"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control pwafs" name="year">
        <option value="#">- Select Year-</option>
        <option value="1"> 1</option>
        <option value="2"> 2</option>
        <option value="3"> 3</option>
        <option value="4"> 4</option>
        <option value="5"> 5</option>
        <option value="6"> 6</option>
        <option value="7"> 7</option>
        <option value="8"> 8</option>
        <option value="9"> 9</option>
        <option value="10"> 10</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="renual_date" id="tbDate" class="form-control pwafr" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['renual_date']) ? $_POST['renual_date'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Enter Renual Date eg:dd/mm/yyyy"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="customer_id" id="tbDate" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['customer_id']) ? $_POST['customer_id'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Enter Customer Id"/>
</div>
<br/>
```

this is php code

```
 <?php
    $domains = new domains;
    if (isset($_POST['add-domain'])) {


        //print_r($_POST['email']);
        //exit;
        $errors = $domains->validate_domains_members();
        if (count($errors)) {
            $emsg = $errors;
            $eclass = "alert-danger";
        } else {

            if ($domains->save($domains->table, $_POST)) {
                unset($_POST);
                $emsg = "User Added Successfully";
                $eclass = "alert-success";
            }
        }
    }
?> 
<?php if (isset($emsg)) { ?>
    <div class="alert <?php echo $eclass; ?>"><?php echo $emsg; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(".pwafs").change(function(){
        //alert("ok");
        //alert($(".pwaf").val());
        var date = $(".pwaf").val();
        var year = date.replace("/", "");
        var year2 = year.replace("/", "");
        var year3 = year2.substring(4, year2);
        var add = +year3 + +$(this).val();
        var final = date.slice(0,-4);
        //alert(final+add);
        $(".pwafr").val(final+add);
    })
```